# Oracle Apex 5: Grand Total in Interactive Report

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

In Oracle Apex 5, for an Interactive Report, if you add a Control Break and an Aggregate (e.g. SUM) it will have a sum for each Control Break group, but not a grand total sum for all of the groups.  How can you display the grand total?

**Please note:** for Classic reports, if a control break is added the grand total is displayed.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps a work around could be to create a *display only* item with a default value type as *PL/SQL Function Body*.

for the code you could put

```
DECLARE
 GRAND_TOTAL NUMBER;
BEGIN

 SELECT SUM(your_column) INTO GRAND_TOTAL FROM your_table;
 RETURN GRAND_TOTAL;

END;
```